# How can I get user's hex input to print as decimal in x86 assembly (16-bit DOS)?

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, nasm

I asked my professor for help. He's deep into his tenure and doesn't really care, so he just kind of gave me a vague solution to the problem. The basic assignment is to take user input (a hex value), convert the value to decimal, and then print it out as such. Here is my code:

```
; SECOND ASSIGNMENT

    org 100h

;equates
cr equ  0dh         ;carriage return
lf equ  0ah         ;line feed

section .data
prompt0: db 0dh, 0ah, "My name is Brandon Copeland. Prepare to enter data! $"
prompt1: db 0dh, 0ah, "Enter a hex digit: $"
prompt2: db 0dh, 0ah, "In decimal it is: $"
prompt3: db 0dh, 0ah, "Do you want to do it again? Press 'y' or 'Y' to continue $"
prompt4: db "Illegal entry: must be 0 - 9 or A - F $"

section .text
start:
    mov ah,9        ;Display string
    mov dx,prompt0  ;Greeting
    int 21h     ;System call

    mov ah,9        ;Display string
    mov dx,prompt1  ;Prompt for first number
    int 21h     ;System call

    mov     bx,0        ;bx holds input value
    mov     ah,1        ;Reads keyboard character
    int 21h     ;System call

    cmp al, '9'     ;compares input to '9'
    je  print       ;if 9, jump to print
    jl  print       ;if less than 9, jump to print
    ja  decConvert  ;if greater than 9, convert A - F to 10 - 15

decConvert:
    and al,11011111b    ; force uppercase
    sub al,65       ; convert 'A'-'F' to 10-15
    pop bx

    mov ah,9
    mov dx,prompt2
    int 21h

    mov ah,2        ;print char
    mov dl,'1'      ;print '1'
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,bl
    int 21h

    jmp repeat

print:
    mov ah,9        
    mov dx, prompt2
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov     dl,al
    int 21h

repeat:
    mov ah,9
    mov dx, prompt3 ;asks user if wants to do again
    int 21h

    mov bx,0        ;gets user answer
    mov ah,1
    int 21h

    cmp al,'y'      ;if y, restart
    je  start
    cmp al,'Y'      ;if Y, restart
    je  start
    jmp exit        ;otherwise, terminate program       ;

exit:
    mov ah,04ch     ;DOS function: exit
    mov al,0        ;exit code
    int 21h     ;call DOS, exit
```

Before walking away, my professor mentioned that since all hex values A - F will start with '1', I can just print out '1' once, and then to print out the next digit, I'd have to pop the contents of al into another register. If you look in the lable "decConvert," I popped al into bx, and later tried to print bl.

The output for numbers 0 - 9 is fine. However, anytime I try to enter A - F, the output is just '1' every time. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no idea what `pop` does, apparently. Consult an instruction set reference.

Hint: you want `push ax` where you have the `pop bx` and you want `pop dx` where you have the `mov dl,bl`.

Also your `sub al,65` is wrong, because it converts to `0..5` and not `'0'..'5'` (ie. you want `sub al, 17`)

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

And no, I guess I'm not entirely clear on the dynamics of push and pop. We barely touched on it in class, and it's not that it matters. Like I said, my professor is so deep into his tenure he doesn't care to explain it. 

If you don't mind, could you maybe explain your solution? I'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: `push` just saves its operand on the stack, and `pop` retrieves it. Since we needed the thing in `dl` I popped into `dx`, you don't need to use the same register. I trust you have no problem with the last paragraph.

Comment: I did change it to sub al, 17, which makes sense after I looked at an ASCII table. I had set it to 65 because that's actually what my professor told me to do. He was barely paying attention and actually walked out half way through his explanation. Tenure.

Anyway, after reading some more about the stack, I think I've identified my source of confusion. Maybe I'm still a little unclear, but I guess what I thought I was doing by popping before pushing was taking something from the call stack, which to my understanding is an implicit stack that handles local variables.